# Cassandra Sails model.count() Works but model.find() and model.findOne() Not Working

Tags: node.js, cassandra, sails.js

I have a `Data` model in Sails using the `sails-cassandra` connection system. Data. `Data.count({...}).exec()` returns 1, but `Data.find({...}).exec()` or `Data.findOne({...}).exec()` return the following error message:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
ResponseError: Undefined name folder in selection clause
  at FrameReader.readError (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/readers.js:276:13)
  at Parser.parseError (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:187:45)
  at Parser.parseBody (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:169:19)
  at Parser._transform (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:103:10)
  at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
  at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
  at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
  at Protocol.ondata (_stream_readable.js:540:20)
  at Protocol.emit (events.js:107:17)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
  at Protocol.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
  at Protocol.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:140:32)
  at Protocol.transformChunk (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:75:8)
  at Protocol._transform (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:26:10)
  at Protocol.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
  at Protocol.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
  at Protocol.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
  at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:540:20)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

  (event loop)
  at RequestHandler.send (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:128:11)
  at Client._getPrepared (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/client.js:581:11)
  at /Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/client.js:399:12
  at fn (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:638:34)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/samuel/Apps/dataapp/node_modules/sails-cassandra/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:554:34)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the construction of the returned attributes since `count()` does not return any of the attributes, where as `find()` and `findOne()` do.

I would look at the attributes on your models. Add and remove each one till you find the offender.